# Mongodb java UpdateOne

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using updateone(filter, updateDocument) to update some attributes in mongodb. However it fails the first time everytime and second succeeds. Same data same everything no change. Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: `Any idea why?`, no. You should post your code.